# zeep client exception. zeep.transport.session.cookies not propagating

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeep

I tried to create a zeep client and use it  by  two methods.

1) I tried to keep everything in a single module . i created the zeep client object   and it was working fine while using a payload.
2) I created a method  which returns a zeep client object for a wsdl. I tried to use this a way as method 1) But getting the below error. 
zeep.exception.Fault : Incoming message could not be authenticated. No valid credentials found
Can someone please advise what I am missing here which causes this error.  My second approach is like this.
\\
    def zeepClient(wsdl):
        ## do all here and return zeep client object.
    return client
    #Now in another module I do call that above method like this
    Client=othermodule.zeepClient(mywsdl)
    Payload={my payload}
    Client.service.myservice(**Payload)
\\

If I do this , I get above error.But if my above piece of code and my method for zeepClient are all in same place. I am not getting error.
Not sure . What that Returned Client object is missing.

Comment: Edited from mobile. Sorry it's crappy

Answer (score 0):

You must provide credentials to the session and then make a request like [here](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/transport.html#http-authentication)

```py
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)
client = Client('http://my-endpoint.com/production.svc?wsdl',
    transport=Transport(session=session))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for coming back. I  do use cookies and the problem mainly here is if I  add my payload in same module . It works. But if I do something like this main it fails. Editing my main question with some sort of sample code for second approach

Comment: Hi. I found the issue. Client.transport.session.cookies not propagating when used as method. Any idea how I can make this work?. Whole idea is to make things reusablewithnless repetitive code.

Comment: i am not sure how , but the issue got fixed today . even i dont see much difference in code to find error.(cant share exact  code  due to security terms) Bad part is i am not able to find the error. please  downvote me . My bad . cant down vote myself  .  earlier cookies were not propagating. But now its  working fine. I am not able to find the reason why the  cookies data  was missing earlier  , but is there now.